# Calling Mail function multiple time in a single script in php

Tags: php, email

I am calling mail function 2 times in my script as below. But I am not getting second email. below is my code...

```
    // Sending email to Client
    $toClient = $name . "<" . $email . ">";
    $header1 = 'From: Name 1 <'.$fromEmail.'>' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: Owner <'.$fromEmail.'>' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $header1 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header1 .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    $mailSentToClient = mail($toClient, 'Email Sent to Owner', "Thank you for contacting, I will get back to you shortly. <br>\n-Owner", $header1);

    // Sending email to Owner
    $toOwner = 'Owner' . "<" . $ownerEmail . ">";
    $header2 = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $header2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header2 .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    $mailSentToOwner = mail($toOwner, 'New Message', $message, $header2);
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If the first one works and the second one does not it probably isn't a coding issue.

Comment: @JohnConde I think code is correct, there is some problem with PHP. Can you pls help me to fix it

Comment: @JohnConde, this is not the duplicate of PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail Question. Can you pls remove that?

Comment: How is not a duplicate? Your email is not arriving. That question explains how to troubleshoot that.

Comment: @JohnConde as per that question the mail is not sending at all. but in my case first mail is going but second mail is not going. and syntax is same for the both

Comment: Exactly. So as my first comments says, it's not a coding issue. Something outside of your code is preventing your email from arriving. That question tells you how to troubleshoot that. Did you read the first answer?

Comment: @JohnConde, I have read the first answer. I am following all the things. but still no luck.

Comment: That answer covers everything this community knows about debugging PHP's failure to send an email. Asking a new question will not get any new information. I recommend doublechecking everything and trying to send each email one at a time and see what happens. If it works when there is only one email being sent on each call to that script, then you know something is blocking that second email. Same goes if you try switching the order of the emails. So, there is still more you can do for debugging this.